# VB split string using html comment as delimiter

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm using VB  to create a html document using a stringbuilder. I want to split the stringbuilder and add more text between some html comments. The string builder looks a bit like this:

```
<html>
<!--STYLE-->
<style>
</style>
<!--STYLE-->
</html>
```

I thought I would be able to do:

```
dim split_doc() as string = sb.tostring().split("<!--STYLE-->")
```

However the outcome is that the stringbuilder is split only on the < rather than the full html comment.

Is it possible to split using the html comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should activate the `Option Strict On` statement at the top of your source-code file to detect and prevent problems like this one.

Probably what happens is that when `Option Strict` is deactivated then the `<!--STYLE-->` word is just turned into an array of chars to call the `String.Split` function that takes an array of `Char`, then it splits the content when any of the chars that composes the `<!--STYLE-->` word is found, starting with the "`<`" char.

To solve this issue, just use the right overload of the `String.Split` function that takes a string as paramater, this way:

```
        Dim html As String =
<a><![CDATA[
<html>
<!--STYLE-->
<style>
</style>
<!--STYLE-->
</html>
]]></a>.Value

    Dim tokens As String() = 
        html.Split({"<!--STYLE-->"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Thank you! I looked up the option strict and didn't really understand it (I'm a newbie!) but putting my delimiter inside the array brackets and adding stringsplitoptions worked.

Comment: Just got my head around the strict option as well, it's really helpful. Wish I had enough rep to give you an up vote for that!

Comment: You are welcome. If you would like to activate by default Option statements automatically for each new source file, see the **Change the Default Project Values** section in this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311329